# Changed .NET target and my solution won't open

Tags: visual-studio-2012, target

I changed my target to NET4.5 to accommodate a library I'm embedding and now my solution won't open properly.  VS seems to think that it's open, but I cannot change solution/project settings or properties, and none of my solution data is available in the explorer.  Any thoughts on what I can do?

After I changed it, VS said that the solution needed to be closed and reopened.  Then it never reopened.

Comment: Sounds a little like you've now got a solution with no project. Try opening the `.Xproj` file directly to recover (where `X` corresponds to your language).

Comment: Same result.  The crazy part is that I can compile and it ends with the same issues I was having before I made the change (can't find assembly - because it wasn't including my embedded DLL since the target NET was incorrect to support it).